# Python - Split List into a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to split a big list into a dictionary. Given a list with say `363` elements I want to divide them such that each key in the dictionary will have a list of 10 values. So a list of 363 elements will have 37 keys (rounded up to nearest 10).The keys will start from `1` and go upto `37`. I wrote a function for the rounding up but i dont know how to split the list while making sure the sequence is maintained and if all the lists (which will be the values of the keys) are joined they will mirror the original list.

This is my rounding up function:

```
def roundup(list_length, atatime=10):
    return ((atatime-(list_length%atatime))+list_length)/atatime
```

Any ideas , suggestions will be really helpfull

Comment: What do you want the keys to be? `0, 1, 2, etc` ?

Comment: Start from `1,2,3` . Ill add that to the post

Comment: You can divy up a list into ten pieces each like so: `[lst[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(lst), 10)]`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @dg123 - yeah it split my list into the kind of pieces i was looking for.

Comment: List is unsorted? Btw, why are you creating such a data structure? Is this preferable to having a dict with all 370 keys, mapping each to its corresponding integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round up and slice appropriately:

```
l = list(range(363)) 
at_a_time = 10
n = len(l)
d, r = divmod(n, at_a_time) 

# if there is a remainder, add 1 to the keys, 363 -> 37 keys 360 -> 36 keys
num_keys = d + 1 if r else d
# get correct slice size based on amount of keys    
sli = n // num_keys

# create "sli" sized chunks
vals = (l[i:i+sli] for i in range(0, n, sli+1)) 
# make dict from `1 to num_keys inclusive and slices
dct = dict(zip(range(1,num_keys+1),vals))
print(dct)
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 3: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], 4: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38], 5: [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48], 6: [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58], 7: [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68], 8: [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78], 9: [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88], 10: [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98], 11: [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108], 12: [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118], 13: [120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128], 14: [130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138], 15: [140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148], 16: [150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158], 17: [160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168], 18: [170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178], 19: [180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188], 20: [190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198], 21: [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208], 22: [210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218], 23: [220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228], 24: [230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238], 25: [240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248], 26: [250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258], 27: [260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268], 28: [270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278], 29: [280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288], 30: [290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298], 31: [300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308], 32: [310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318], 33: [320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328], 34: [330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338], 35: [340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348], 36: [350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358], 37: [360, 361, 362]}
```

If you don't want the list sliced evenly and the remainder to be added to the last key just use your `atatime` for each slice (10 in the example code):

```
 vals = (l[i:i+at_a_time] for i in range(0, n, sli+1))
```

We can also use `num_keys = n + (at_a_time - 1) // at_a_time` to round as any value that has a remainder `// at_a_time` will be rounded up adding `at_a_time - 1` to it , any number evenly divisible  will not.

You can do it  all in a dict comprehension making some changes to the code but I think you will hopefully learn more from explicit code.

Comment: if `at_a_time` is set to `10`, then the last key only has number upto '332'. On   changing it into `11`, it goes all the way upto `362`

Comment: @letsc, was missing a + 1

Comment: Another issue. if im dealing with a list of strings then the dict returned has integers and not the strings

Comment: @letsc, if you pass a list of strings then you will get  strings,python is not going to change the type

Comment: I just tried it . Create a function with your code which takes in a list. The return is all integers.

Comment: @letsc. no that is not possible, are you actually using a the list of strings and not  the example list(range) in my code?

Comment: nevermind. I was passing length of list instead of the list itself. Thanks

Comment: ok, there is no way python will ever change your data unless you explicitly want it to change

Answer (score 0):

The following dict comprehension slices the list into the required number of slices.

In other words, `idx+1` is the key, whereas `lst[atatime*idx:atatime*(idx+1)]` is the value of a dictionary defined using dict-comprehension. The value is a slice of `atatime` length. We iterate over the (rounded upwards) size of the list divided by the chunk-size using an xrange iterator.

```
from math import ceil
{idx+1: lst[atatime*idx:atatime*(idx+1)] for idx in xrange(int(ceil(float(len(lst))/atatime)))}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add a small description to the code which would let me understand it rather than blindly copying it

Comment: @letsc A piece of advice: It's better to wait a while before accepting answers. Of course, you can accept this one if it satisfies you, but waiting a little bit gives others the chance (and incentive) to try and answer you in different ways. Often, you end up with many more answers than you'd otherwise have gotten.

Comment: I just applied this to the list I have I realized the problem pointed out by @PadraicCunningham